# Can I use cStringIO the same as StringIO?

Tags: python, c, stringio

I did this:

```
import cStringIO.StringIO as StringIO
```

And I realize I've been using it everywhere.  Is that fine?
Is it treated the same as StringIO?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They are not the same. `cStringIO` doesn't correctly handle unicode characters.

```
>>> StringIO.StringIO().write(u'\u0080')

>>> cStringIO.StringIO().write(u'\u0080')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x80' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: @TIMEX: Do you need support for Unicode characters beyond ASCII?

Comment: No idea. I'm just using StringIO for pictures. and reading pictures , then uploadinng it to S3

Comment: @Mark Byers - Do you know if cStringIO handles Unicode better in Python3?

Comment: @Omnifarious: There's no cStringIO in Python3.  It's replaced with io.StringIO and io.BytesIO, which, in line with Python3, are for Unicode and byte strings respectively, and which use native implementations automatically if available (the need to load a native implementation like cStringIO manually in Python2 is most likely a strange API compatibility artifact).

Comment: On the other hand, if you encode the strings yourself, you can still give them to a cStringIO.  For example, `cStringIO.StringIO().write(u'\u2603')` doesn't work, but `cStringIO.StringIO().write(u'\u2603'.encode('utf-8'))` works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Nor can you set attributes on a cStringIO.StringIO instance:

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> s = StringIO()
>>> s.name = 'myfile'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'cStringIO.StringO' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Several libraries depend on File-like objects having either a `name` or `content_type` attribute, so cStringIO.StringIO does not work in these instances.